# How do I approach iterating rows in pandas dataframe looking for specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me on how to approach a problem?

I need to iterate over each row in a pandas dataframe looking to see if a value in the number column is recorded in the last month data or the future month data, and return True on the second occurrence if it is there or false if it is not there.

I've tried searching the web looking for possible ways to approach this problem and used a pd.iterate(), pd.any() to no success

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be helpful.

Comment: please provide sample input and output